# Device Driver regmap_update_bits Issue

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver, imx6

I am writing the imx290 csi-2 mipi camera driver based on ov5640 omnivision csi-2 camera. I have also imx290 reference driver and I have to make it work on imx6q processor so I am modifying make changes depending on references.
I have faced with some problem which is writing values to the register. in imx290 `regmap_update_bits(regmap, reg, mask, regbits);` are used in the

`static int imx290_write_regbits(struct regmap *regmap, unsigned reg,
        unsigned regbits, unsigned nbits)` function  and I need to make some change about these values to be reliable with ;  `i2c_master_send(ov5640_data.i2c_client, au8Buf, 3);`

I made research and look at the header files but I couldn't find it. If you have an info about that would you help me to figure it out?

Thanks..
Best Regards.

Comment: I figured out what it is doing `regmap_update_bits(regmap,reg,mask,regbits);` it masking the register bits and write the regbits value to the masked register bits , but I didnt understand what the regmap is doing in that macro ?

Comment: It's classical, though atomic in context of regmap, RMW operation.